# Maintenance page appears during login

Tags: commerce, users, maintenance-mode

I need your help :

When any user logs into my website (admins too), the maintenance page is displayed with the url "**/node?destination=node**", while maintenance mode is surely **off**.

Then, if the user calls the host base url, the website is working normally and user is properly logged-in. 
The maintenance page never appears again while maintenance mode is off.

If you've got any idea please keep me in touch, I'm lost ^^

Thanks in advance.

--
Info(s) : Drupal 7.31 + Module Drupal Commerce

Comment: Sounds like a content caching issue. Is there something like varnish in play, which may have cached `/node?destination=node` during maintenance mode and is now serving it from cache?

Comment: I'm not using any Varnish or other caching system than Drupal's cache itself. I cleared it many times but no effect... Do you think I may clear some log tables from database, like cache_* , access_log, ect.. ?

Comment: Clearing Drupal cache automatically clears all `cache_` tables, and logs do not affect this. You could try to restart your webserver (apache/nginix) though. Also be aware that Drupal 7.31 is vulnerable to https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005 what might be an explanation for this strange behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this security breach. I'll update the core to the 7.43 version and keep you in touch.

Comment: The issue is that simply updating might not be enough as malicious scripts could have been installed already. The advice was to empty your server and start over. It is up to you to make this decision and I will not tell you what to do. If you are confident enough to continue with your current setup, you can have a look at the [hacked module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) to check your installation against the original files, but even then the exploit might have moved out of the Drupal folder and nested elsewhere. Basically there is not much we can do in this situation, sorry...